# how to calculate the angle(s) of $\ -\sqrt{2i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

So $\tan \phi = \frac yx $

But my $\ x = 0$ , so how do I find the respective angle?

The context is me trying to find the roots of $\  -\sqrt{2i}$

It should be something to the respect of $\ (1+i)$  and $\ (-1-i)$ or

$\  \sqrt{2} e^{i \cdot \frac \pi 4 }$ and $\  \sqrt{2} e^{3i \cdot \frac \pi 4 }$

but i don't really get how I'm supposed to get there without finding $\ \phi $ since for the squareroots it's also it's $\  \sqrt{r} e^{i \frac \phi 2 }$

I feel like I'm missing a vital bit here.

Comment: Use that $i = e^{i\frac \pi 2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

- write $2i$ in exponential form that is $2i=2e^{i\frac{\pi}2}$
- calculate $\sqrt{2i}$ that is $\sqrt 2 e^{i\frac{\pi}4} \quad \sqrt 2 e^{i\frac{5\pi}4}$
- take $-\sqrt{2i}$

Comment: why is $\ 2i = 2e^{i  \frac \pi 2 }$ (?) and pls don't say "because $\ i = e^{i  \frac \pi 2 }$ " :)

Comment: $e^{i\theta }=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$ @BlkPengu

Comment: the foundamental relationship is $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$

Comment: and since $Arg(i) = \pi/2$ you find the result

Comment: @BlkPengu take a look here for some notes on complex roots http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Roots.aspx

Comment: @BlkPengu is you don't like exponential for you can use polar form, they are equivalent, are you aware about it?